# Error ORA-02291: Integrity Constraint - 1:1 instead of 1:M?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

I see that the parent key isn't found. In my case, both FK_PLAYERTEAM and FK_PLAYERPOSITION. I noticed that everywhere I see this error, it's an order of operations mistake. The values for position, or team id were not entered in before entering or referencing those values in the Player table. It seems in my case, that once there are 14 players entered, the same amount of teams there are, that I can no longer enter any more players.

So do I have a one to one rather than a one a to many relationship here? Please review my work! I'm new, doing this for my summer class project.

```
/*CITY TABLE*/
DROP TABLE CITY;
CREATE TABLE CITY (
  ID int        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME varchar2(255)    NOT NULL,
  STATE varchar2(255)   NOT NULL,
  COUNTRY varchar2(100) default 'USA'
);

/*SEASON TABLE*/
DROP TABLE SEASON;
CREATE TABLE SEASON (
   ID int           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   YEAR varchar2(4)         NOT NULL
);

/*POSITION TABLE*/
DROP TABLE POSITION;
CREATE TABLE POSITION (
   ID int       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   NAME varchar2(255)       NOT NULL,
   NAME_ABR varchar2(3)     NOT NULL,
   CATEGORY varchar2(255)   NOT NULL
);

/*TEAM TABLE*/
DROP TABLE TEAM;
CREATE TABLE TEAM (
   ID int                    NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME varchar2(255)        DEFAULT 'FREE AGENT',
  SHORT_NAME varchar2(3)    NOT NULL,
  COACH_NAME varchar2(255)  NULL,
  CITY_ID int            NULL,
   CONSTRAINT FK_TEAMCITY   FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES CITY(ID)
);

*/PLAYER TABLE*/
DROP TABLE PLAYER;
CREATE TABLE PLAYER (
   ID int                    NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   FIRSTNAME varchar2(255)   NOT NULL, 
   LASTNAME varchar2(255)    NOT NULL, 
   DATE_OF_BIRTH varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
   PLAYER_NUM int            NOT NULL,
   COUNTRY varchar2(3)     DEFAULT 'USA',
   TEAM_ID int               NULL,
   CONSTRAINT FK_PLAYERTEAM
   FOREIGN KEY (ID)  REFERENCES TEAM(ID),
   POSITION_ID int          NULL,
   CONSTRAINT FK_PLAYERPOSITION
   FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES POSITION(ID)
);

/*MATCH TABLE*/
DROP TABLE MATCH;
CREATE TABLE MATCH (
    ID  int     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    GAME_DAY date   NOT NULL,
    GAME_TIME timestamp NOT NULL,
    WIN_TEAM int        NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_WIN_TEAM
    FOREIGN KEY (WIN_TEAM) REFERENCES TEAM(ID),
    HOME_TEAM int        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_HOME_TEAM
    FOREIGN KEY (HOME_TEAM) REFERENCES TEAM(ID),
    AWAY_TEAM int        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_AWAY_TEAM
    FOREIGN KEY (AWAY_TEAM) REFERENCES TEAM(ID),
    SEASON_ID int       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_SEASON_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (SEASON_ID) REFERENCES SEASON(ID)
);

/*GOALS TABLE*/
DROP TABLE GOALS;
CREATE TABLE GOALS (
    ID int      NOT NULL,
    MINUTE int  NOT NULL,
    MATCH_ID int    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_GOALS_MATCH
    FOREIGN KEY (MATCH_ID) REFERENCES MATCH(ID),
    PLAYER_ID int   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_GOALS_PLAYER
    FOREIGN KEY (PLAYER_ID) REFERENCES PLAYER(ID)
);
```

As i enter values here is my order.

```
/*CITY POPULATE*/
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('1','Springfield','MA','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('2','Toledo','OH','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('3','New Orleans','LA','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('4','Erie','PA','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('5','Dallas','TX','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('6','Denver','CO','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('7','Reno','NV','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('8','Scranton','PA','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('9','Virginia Beach','VA','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('10','Green Bay','WI','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('11','Atlanta','GA','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('12','Columbus','OH','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('13','Orlando','FL','USA');
INSERT INTO CITY (ID,NAME,STATE,COUNTRY) VALUES ('14','Austin','TX','USA');

/*SEASON POPULATE*/
INSERT INTO SEASON (ID,YEAR) VALUES (1,2013);
INSERT INTO SEASON (ID,YEAR) VALUES (2,2014);
INSERT INTO SEASON (ID,YEAR) VALUES (3,2015);
INSERT INTO SEASON (ID,YEAR) VALUES (4,2016);
INSERT INTO SEASON (ID,YEAR) VALUES (5,2017);
INSERT INTO SEASON (ID,YEAR) VALUES (6,2018);

/*POSITION POPULATE*/
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('1','GoalKeeper','GK','GoalKeeper');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('2','Sweeper','SW','Defender');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('3','Centerback','CB','Defender');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('4','Leftback','LB','Defender');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('5','Rightback','RB','Defender');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('6','Left-Wingback','LWB','Defender');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('7','Right-Wingback','RWB','Defender');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('8','Defending Midfielder','DM','Midfielder');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('9','Central Midfielder','CM','Midfielder');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('10','Attacking Midfielder','AM','Midfielder');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('11','Left Winger','LW','Midfielder');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('12','Right Winger','RW','Midfielder');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('13','Center Forward','CF','Forward');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('14','Withdrawn Forward','WF','Forward');
INSERT INTO POSITION
VALUES ('15','Striker','S','Forward');

/*TEAM POPULATE*/
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('1','Springfield FC','SFC','Dolan Mcguire','1');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('2','Toleda Stars FC','TS','Wing Warren','2');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('3','Louisiana AF','LAF','Zane Valentine','3');
INSERT INTO TEAM 
VALUES ('4','Erie FC','EAF','Brenda Rios','4');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('5','FC Dallas','FCD','Mark Horne','5');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('6','Colorado Rapids','CR','Brian Cameron','6');
INSERT INTO TEAM 
VALUES ('7','Reno 1868 FC','RFC','Russel Klabough','7');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('8','Scranton Football','SF','Mark York','8');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('9','Beach FC','BFC','Zidane Zidan','9');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('10','Green Bay Phoenix','GBP','Shad Ramos','10');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('11','Atlanta United FC','AFC','Gernado Martino','11');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('12','Columbus Crew SC','CCS','Gregg Berhalter','12');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('13','Orlando City SC','OSC','Jason Kreis','13');
INSERT INTO TEAM
VALUES ('14','Austin Aztex','AAX','Adrian Health','14');

INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (1,'Ashton','Hewitt','05/07/1991',31,'USA',10,13);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (2,'Fuller','Farrell','08/12/1987',45,'USA',3,2);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (3,'Allistair','Mccullough','05/20/1993',20,'USA',5,14);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (4,'Connor','Caldwell','03/28/1996',66,'USA',14,5);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (5,'Igor','Britt','09/27/1992',45,'USA',12,11);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (6,'Cyrus','Barron','10/20/1991',41,'USA',7,1);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (7,'Quamar','Melendez','09/28/1986',20,'USA',7,15);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (8,'Dustin','Sandoval','07/05/1987',34,'USA',11,9);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (9,'Addison','Santana','12/07/1994',17,'USA',8,10);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (10,'Christian','Murphy','11/06/1986',73,'USA',5,15);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (11,'Isaiah','Reeves','03/23/1990',59,'USA',1,8);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (12,'Nero','Luna','03/14/1996',31,'USA',10,4);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (13,'Deacon','Maddox','05/10/1989',54,'USA',4,5);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (14,'Macaulay','Velez','07/13/1994',33,'USA',7,15);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (15,'Jamal','Cox','02/03/1990',44,'USA',12,11);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (16,'Axel','Dominguez','01/13/1996',15,'USA',3,5);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (17,'Jakeem','Barlow','03/09/1994',61,'USA',12,6);
INSERT INTO PLAYER (ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,PLAYER_NUM,COUNTRY,TEAM_ID,POSITION_ID) VALUES (18,'Mufutau','Hodges','09/09/1987',69,'USA',1,9);
```

But I end up getting after the 14th line:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SQL_DFIJAZERMYRXHWLVJVYDVODHP.FK_PLAYERTEAM) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SQL_DFIJAZERMYRXHWLVJVYDVODHP.FK_PLAYERPOSITION) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SQL_DFIJAZERMYRXHWLVJVYDVODHP.FK_PLAYERPOSITION) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SQL_DFIJAZERMYRXHWLVJVYDVODHP.FK_PLAYERPOSITION) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying an incorrect foreign key constraint, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEAM (
  ID int                    NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME varchar2(255)        DEFAULT 'FREE AGENT',
  SHORT_NAME varchar2(3)    NOT NULL,
  COACH_NAME varchar2(255)  NULL,
  CITY_ID int            NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_TEAMCITY   FOREIGN KEY (CITY_ID) REFERENCES CITY(ID)
);
```

Comment: you are the best my friend.

Comment: You can also declare the FK as part of the column definition and inherit the datatype: `city_id constraint fk_teamcity references city(id)`